# Simulate t-tests of mean differences

Tags: r, t-test, p-value, simulation

I would like to simulate t-tests of mean differences. I would like to simulate data based on

1. pre-specified (desired) mean difference between the variables **and**
2. desired t value  3) **and** p-value

Basically with desired mean difference, t-value and desired p-value. Is it possible to simulate the data and if so how to go about it?. (I am working with R)

Comment: If you mean an equal-variance t-test, then if you frame this t-test as a regression, you essentially already have an answer to your question in an earlier question of yours.

Comment: thank you glen. I was hoping it should be similar but I do not know how to frame a t-test as a regression, in this case when I am testing the difference of means of two variables. A little help and I will look into it. thanks

Comment: Compare the output of `t.test(extra ~ group, data = sleep,var.equal=TRUE)` with that from `summary(lm(extra ~ group, data = sleep))` (this is a built in data set). Note that the t-statistic and p-value for the coefficient in the regression is identical to that for the t-test. This is no accident. The two models are identical. Note that the regression is on the group dummy that's automatically generated from the factor `group`. Note also that with a single regressor, my comments about p-value for the overall regression apply equally to the p-value for the coefficient.

Comment: Glen, so you mean specifying the "t-value" requires either manipulating the coefficients or S.D's?

Comment: ... and sample size or df, of course (in regression more generally, dependence in X's also matters). In the case of the t-test, the coefficient would be the difference in means, and the relevant SD is the pooled standard deviation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. What you want is a power analysis, which will help you find the parameters necessary to make up some data.

See the [pwr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pwr/index.html) package in R. Use pwr.t.test(). choose 1) how many samples you want and 2) the p-value (alpha) you're shooting for. set power to 0.5. Take note of the effect size (d) returned in the output.

Next decide on the mean difference you want and divide it by d. That's the standard deviation you want to use when simulating data.

Then use rnorm() to make up your two data sets using all of these parameters.

Then, if you want one data set for which a t-test gives you a certain p-value, you can iteratively generate data sets (use repeat), use t-tests to compare the difference between them, check the p-value, and save the data sets if they meet your p-value criteria. pseudo-code looks like this:

```
repeat {
  set1 <- rnorm()
  set2 <- rnorm()
  tt <- t.test(set1, set2)
  pv <- tt$p.value
  if (pv < 0.05 & pv > 0.04) {
    break
  }
}
```

Then you will have two data sets for which the t-test gives you a p-value < 0.05 and > 0.06.

Although it looks based on comments like somebody might have a faster solution.

Comment: This approach doesn't really work correctly--it is biased towards a lower p-value than specified--and it is much less efficient than directly computing the standard deviation needed to achieve a specified t (or p) value.

Comment: edited to be more specific.

Comment: thanks. this was very specific. I will report how it is working for me.

Comment: 1) is there a way I can specify the t-value here? A specific value?  2) I have the two means, t-value. I would like to generate data that will satisfy the means and the mean difference t-value

Comment: I can compute the p-value from the specific t-value. But I am not sure of there is a more efficient way.

Comment: see line 5 of my code, then use statistic instead of p.value. in the future, if you look at the "Values" section of the help file, it will tell you what is available for you to work with.

Comment: @tim.farkas The `pv < 0.05 & pv > 0.06` rule is contradictory. Value cannot be *at the same time* (`&`) lower then 0.05 and higher then 0.06!

Comment: very true. my bad. fixed.